# How to implement versioning in Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure-mobile-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgrhq.png)I want to implement versioning in azure mobile service so I am not able to find the endpoints to configure and based on version number it will take the code.
Now URL is 
http://{{host}}/tables/EntityName

but my requirement is 
http://{{host}}/tables/v1/EntityName
 or 
http://{{host}}/tables/v2/EntityName

So please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, I followed [Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/How-to-Version-Your-Service) to check the versioning with azure mobile app project. You could refer to the details below to achieve your purpose.

Install the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning) package.

Enable the API versioning in your `Startup.MobileApp.cs` as follows:

```
public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
    {
        ConstraintMap =
            {
                ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint )
            }
    };
    config.AddApiVersioning();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);

    //your mobile configuration

    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

For your `TableController`, you could define it as follows:

**tables/v1.0/todoitem**

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[RoutePrefix("tables/v{version:apiVersion}/todoitem")]
public class TodoItemController : TableController<ToDoItem>
{
    private MobileServiceContext context;
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<ToDoItem>(context, Request);
    }

    [Route]
    // GET tables/v{version}/todoitem
    public IQueryable<ToDoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
    {   
        return Query();
    }
 }
```

**tables/v2.0/todoitem**

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ControllerName("TodoItem")]
[RoutePrefix("tables/v{version:apiVersion}/todoitem")]
public class TodoItemV2Controller : TableController<ToDoItem>
{
    private MobileServiceContext context;
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<ToDoItem>(context, Request);
    }

    [Route]
    // GET tables/v{version}/todoitem
    public IQueryable<ToDoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
    {   
        return Query();
    }
 }
```

For more details, you could refer to [ASP.NET API Versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unable to do routing with this approach as I am using Azure Mobile App(AMS) Project.